# How to parse an image from JSON into swift4

Tags: json, swift, codable, decodable, encodable

I am trying to pull images from my database in swift. I can retrieve the price, video, and p_name but not the images. I would like to update the updateImage `UIImageView` with the image from the database but I get two errors.

Error one says:

> Type 'ViewController.Class' does not conform to protocol 'Encodable'

Error two says:

> Type 'ViewController.Class' does not conform to protocol 'Dec

What are some good work-arounds for this?

Here is the JSON:

```
{
"id":"1",
"p_name":"item_one",
"image":"item_one.png"
}
{
"id":"2","p_name":
"item_two","image":
"item_two.img"
}
```

And the swift code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var updateLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var updateImage: UILabel!

struct Class: Codable
{
    let id: String
    let p_name: String
    let image: String

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    let url = URL(string: "http://host-2:8888//getClasses.php")

    // Load the URL
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
        // If there are any errors don't try to parse it, show the error
        guard let data = data, error == nil else { print(error!); return }

        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        let classes = try! decoder.decode([Class].self, from: data)
        // Print out the classes to the console - try sticking this in a table view :)
        for myClass in classes {

            self.updateLabel.text = myClass.p_name
            self.updateImage.text = myClass.image

        }

    }).resume()

    }
}
```

Comment: Add the JSON response you are getting.

Comment: Usually, the image returned from a request to some server will be as a URL link. So you need to take that link and use the appropriate initializer of UIImage.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if the keys that you are getting from API are same as the property names in `Codable Type`, then you don't need to specify `enum CodingKeys` explicitly, i.e. you can simply use:

```
struct Class: Codable
{
    let id: String
    let p_name: String
    let image: String
}
```

As far as I understand, you must decode the `JSON data` you are getting in the following way:

```
    let jsonString = """
    [
        {"id": "1", "p_name": "P1", "image": "V1"},
        {"id": "2", "p_name": "P2", "image": "V2"},
        {"id": "3", "p_name": "P3", "image": "V3"}
    ]
    """
    if let jsonData = jsonString.data(using: .utf8)
    {
        let obj = try? JSONDecoder().decode([Class].self, from: jsonData)
        print(obj)
    }
```

In the above code, I have just used a sample `JSON string`. For more clarification, you must add the exact `JSON` response you are getting from the API.

Now if you are also expecting an image url from API, you haven't added any property to store that url string in `struct Class`.

Comment: Sorry the video constant was actually supposed to be named image.

Comment: I’ve updated the above code with image instead of video. Try it and you are good to go. Let me know if you still face any issues. Accept the answer if it works for you. Happy coding 

Comment: Also, your JSON image string must contain the url to image not just the name as you specified above. In case you are only using image name, that image must be present in the assets of your project to get it working.